# SMTP server php error, Tried so much approches and no one worked

Tags: php, email, smtp

I'm trying to test sending emails from my website, I'm working on Localhost
I used the function MAIL by this way

```
$to      = 'el.badr@live.fr' ;
    $subject = ' Sharing QG ' ;
    $message = ' Testing ';
    $headers = 'From : badreddinebaim@gmail.com';
    echo '<form method="POST"> <input type="submit" name="message"/>  </form>';;
    if (isset($_POST['message'])) { mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); }
```

And in my PHP.ini I've put this

```
[mail function]
```

; For Win32 only.
;SMTP =smtp.gmail.com

; For Win32 only.
;sendmail_from = badreddinebaim@gmail.com

But I still receive this error

```
 Warning: mail(): &quot;sendmail_from&quot; not set in php.ini or custom &quot;From:&quot; header missing
```

Comment: Semicolons `;` are used to make a line a comment

Comment: Why do you have two semicolons after echo ?

Comment: Try Example #3  [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php).

Comment: Maz although not needed the extra semi colon will not cause any side effects. Regarding the issue at hand as per the posted extract the directives for mail are commented out so will not work

Comment: The third example show the exact same error :/ 
Any help to just find my SMTP :(